# AND operation with 0xFFFF and subtraction of 0x7FFF

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, data-conversion, adc

I am facing problems in understanding a code that handles the 16-bits output data of a SAR ADC.
More specifically, I am not sure about the meaning of the bit-wise operations shown in the code below. From what I have understood, the `& 0xFFFF` is used to convert into positive the negative representation of a binary number, while I do not get the purpose of `-0x7FFF`. May you help me, please?

```
uint16_t adc_output;
int32_t mVals = 0;
mVals = ( ((int32_t)( adc_output )) & 0xFFFF ) - 0x7FFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

`adc_output & 0xFFFF` is used to mask the *low 16 bits* of `adc_output`, so the result will be in the range [0, 65535]

After that a subtraction of 0x7FFF = 32767 would be used to *convert the output range to [-32767, 32768]*. It's not quite useful and is probably a bug. The correct range should be **[-32768, 32767]** which is the range of a 16-bit [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) number

Comment: Hi Phuclv, thanks for the quick answer. If so, why do we need to convert the ```uint16_t``` into a ```int32_t```? Would an ```int16_t``` be enough? Moreover, can you be a little clearer about the concept "adc_output & 0xFFFF is used to mask the low 16 bits of adc_output", please?

Comment: @lucaaudino I guess it's done like that in case `int` is a 16-bit type, for example on most common MCUs where an ADC is used. In that case `adc_output - 0x7FFF` may invoke UB due to overflow. It's not necessary though because in that case the math is done in unsigned int and can be cast back to signed. Note that the expression also contains lots of unnecessary parentheses